# Displaying all the records from the database based on no-of views using codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi i am trying to fetch the records from database based on no-of-views of the page.But unable to fetch all the records getting only one record.here is my code.

**Controller:**

```
function buzzling()
{
    $data['records2'] = $this->blogs_model->get_all_buzzling();
    $data['mainpage'] = 'buzzling';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

**Model:**

```
function get_all_buzzling()
{
    $this->db->select('B.*');
    $this->db->from('blogs AS B');
    $this->db->where(array('B.status'=>1));
    $this->db->order_by("ne_views", "asc");
    $q=$this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="right">
    <?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
        <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>
            <h1 class="headline2"><span class="headline">Buzzing</span></h1>
            <div class="clearfix float-my-children">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/images/blogimages/thumbs/<?php echo $r->image_path;?>" width=100>
                <div class="blogclasstext1"><?php echo $r->description;?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ; endif;?>
    </div>
```

Sample database table

```
blog_id   image       description status ne_views
1         image.png   description  1      3
2         image.png   description  1      2
3         image.png   description  1      4
4         image.png   description  1      1
```

Comment: post your table sample as well

Comment: you can `echo $q->num_rows();` in model. how many data in your table?

Comment: check your where condition as your post blog records status = 1.

Comment: @razibalmamun i have 5 rows data in my table

Comment: Show your returned array using `print_r($records2)`

Comment: @amit sample table as been updated

Comment: Show your returned array using `var_dump($records2)`

Comment: Your code seems correct. Show your returned array using `var_dump($records2)` as suggested by others.

Comment: @RejoanulAlam not getting anything

Comment: $data['records2'] = $this->blogs_model->get_all_buzzling();
  var_dump($records2);
  $data['mainpage'] = 'buzzling';
  $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);  not getting anything

Comment: in your view file on the top you can write `echo "<pre>";var_dump($records2);`

Comment: `$data['records2'] = $this->blogs_model->get_all_buzzling(); var_dump($data['records2'])` and now show the result

Comment: @RejoanulAlam not getting anything

Comment: @razibalmamun not displaying any data

Comment: @user7047368 what its showing `var_dump($data['records2'])` ?? show this output

Comment: print your query and check in database. you can print the query by doing this: `print_r($this->db->last_query());`

Comment: @RejoanulAlam not displaying anything

Comment: @PathikVejani function get_all_buzzling()
 {
     $this->db->select('B.*');
  $this->db->from('blogs AS B');
  $this->db->where(array('B.status'=>1));
  $this->db->order_by("ne_views", "asc");  
  print_r($this->db->last_query());
    $q=$this->db->get();
  
  if($q->num_rows()>0)
       {
    
  return $q->result();
   }
     else
  {
  return false;
  }
 }  Not getting any data

Comment: @user7047368 what is the printed query?

Comment: i didnt get any query @PathikVejani

Comment: @user7047368 echo **$this->db->last_query()** after this: `$q=$this->db->get(); `

Comment: @PathikVejani not getting what you are saying

Comment: @user7047368 do this: function get_all_buzzling()
{
    $this->db->select('B.*');
    $this->db->from('blogs AS B');
    $this->db->where(array('B.status'=>1));
    $this->db->order_by("ne_views", "asc");
    $q=$this->db->get();
    echo $this->db->last_query()
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127244/discussion-between-user7047368-and-pathik-vejani).

Comment: Solved the issue @PathikVejani

Comment: solved the issue @razibalmamun

Comment: @user7047368 what was the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was call `$this->blogs_model->get_all_buzzling();` in another method.
Please use `$this->blogs_model->get_all_buzzling();` in `article()` method not `buzzling()` on your `blogs` controller.

```
<?php
function article()
{
    $data['records2'] = $this->blogs_model->get_all_buzzling();
    $data['mainpage'] = 'buzzling';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
?>
```